# software which works over internet

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I develop a software with C# and SQL server 2014 for a drugstore which can generate bill and show reports. now i want to share this software with two computer one should be cashier and the other one should be admin for adding stock in inventory, how can i make my software accessible to both computer using local network.
Thanks : )

Comment: Use dedicated SQL server in one of the machines and change connectionstrings?

Comment: 1) Use a window credential in the SQL database.  2) Put two computer in same User Group. 3)   Create a User Account that is accessible from both com[uters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can use a centralized client-server based architecture..where the database and backend will be stored on server and u can access it using ur frontend thourgh a connection to server and its effect will be reflected in server which can be seen by all user!!

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir, can you give me further info and link how can i make like this. : )

Comment: nothing special u have to do...just edit ur database connection code..and put the address of server machine..then u can access it with any other machine in network...make sure to add exception in ur firewall setting..or turn of firewall

Comment: here is my connecting string         SqlConnection mycon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SONY\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Docter_Plus;Integrated Security=True"); for the first machine which is server, how i need to edit for second machine????

Answer (score 0):

If all communication is based on the SQL server (Stock, purchases, ...), then you don't need a direct connection between the two computers. It's enough if both can access the SQL server you mentioned!

Comment: All communication is based on the SQL Server, my question is how can i access from second computer with the software to the first computer with has SQL server install on it

Comment: You need to make sure that the SQL server and your firewall is correctly configured so the second computer can access the server on the first one. In your c# code you simply have to change the connection string of the SQL host from "localhost" or "127.0.0.1" to the local ip of the SQL server

Comment: can i install and configure the software at first computer and make a shortcut of software to the second computer????

Answer (score 0):

Since you need your software to work on network (in your case, two computers), the approach you need to follow is:

1. Host the database on a computer (database server) that is shared by all computers on the network. It can be with in a LAN or on the Internet (if you need so).
2. Modify the `connectionstring` in your application to connect to that database server.
3. Install the application on any number of computers that you want.

This will solve your issue.

Suppose, later you want to access the same database via website, you just need to create a website that connects with the database server and displays the records from the database.

So basic thing that you must need to know that it is the `connectionstring` that really matters and what are your needs.
Thanks, hope it helps.

Comment: here is my Connection string for server machine that works on server         SqlConnection mycon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SONY\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Docter_Plus;Integrated Security=True"); how i need to change for the second machine????

Comment: You need only a single `connectionstring` on all your softwares. You just need to put database server at some computer and connect with that. That's it.

Comment: i did sir, but other machine didn't connect to the Sql Database, i think some how i need to make SQL server discoverable for all computer - and my machines network has no problem.

Comment: your database server should allow remote connections. Try to google about it or search on stackoverflow itself. Once you will get it connected, you are all set to go.